# std::bind a member function at "top-level"

Tags: c++, methods, c++20, stdbind

I figured I could initialize a type that takes a callable with std::bind to a member function at top level. However, I seem to make a mistake. I just can't point my fingers where. Compiler errors seem pretty arbitrary...

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:26,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:26,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:26,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:26,startLineNumber:14),source:%27%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+Callable%3E%0Astruct+timer%0A%7B%0A++++template+%3Ctypename+%3D+std::enable_if_t%3Cstd::is_invocable_v%3CCallable%3E,+void%3E%3E%0A++++timer(Callable+func)%0A++++++++:+func_+%7Bfunc%7D%0A++++%7B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++void+invoke()+const+%7B%0A++++++++func_()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++Callable+func_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+some_struct%0A%7B%0A++++void+do_something()+%7B%0A++++++++timer_.invoke()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++void+request()+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22Hello%5Cn%22)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++const+timer%3Cdecltype(std::bind(%26some_struct::request,+some_struct*))%3E+timer_+%7B+std::bind(%26some_struct::request,+this)+%7D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++some_struct+obj%3B%0A++++obj.do_something()%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.66057441253264,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-O2%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:43.35736354273945,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:56.64263645726055,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.33942558746736,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdio>

template <typename Callable>
struct timer
{
    template <typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<Callable>, void>>
    timer(Callable func)
        : func_ {func}
    {
    }

    void invoke() const {
        func_();
    }

    Callable func_;
};

struct some_struct
{
    void do_something() {
        timer_.invoke();
    }

    void request() {
        printf("Hello\n");
    }

    const timer<decltype(std::bind(&some_struct::request, some_struct*))> timer_ { std::bind(&some_struct::request, this) };
};

int main()
{
    some_struct obj;
    obj.do_something();
}
```

**EDIT**: Here's the errors (gcc 12.2):

```
<source>:31:70: error: expected primary-expression before '*' token
   31 |     const timer<decltype(std::bind(&some_struct::request, some_struct*))> timer_ { std::bind(&some_struct::request, this) };
      |                                                                      ^
<source>:31:71: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
   31 |     const timer<decltype(std::bind(&some_struct::request, some_struct*))> timer_ { std::bind(&some_struct::request, this) };
      |                                                                       ^
<source>:31:73: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   31 |     const timer<decltype(std::bind(&some_struct::request, some_struct*))> timer_ { std::bind(&some_struct::request, this) };
      |                                                                         ^
<source>:31:123: error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const int' in initialization
   31 |     const timer<decltype(std::bind(&some_struct::request, some_struct*))> timer_ { std::bind(&some_struct::request, this) };
      |                                                                                                                           ^
<source>: In member function 'void some_struct::do_something()':
<source>:24:16: error: request for member 'invoke' in '((some_struct*)this)->some_struct::timer_', which is of non-class type 'const int'
   24 |         timer_.invoke();
      |         

   ^~~~~~
```

Comment: You are trying to write a type as as an argument to a function call (`some_struct*`). That doesn't make syntactical sense. Use [`std::invoke_result_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) to determine the type of a call result from types instead of expressions. But what is the purpose of `timer_`? If you want to be able to modify the callable it stores later, `timer` should store a `std::function`, not the callable type itself, which will differ between different callables even with the same signature.

Comment: Also `template <typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<Callable>, void>>` doesn't work for SFINAE. It will cause a hard compilation error if `Callable` is not invocable. Since you are using C++20, you can simply use a `requires` clause instead of `std::enable_if_t` and since it is constraining `Callable` it should go after `template <typename Callable>` not on the constructor.

Comment: @user17732522 I know but I thought that decltype just needs the types, not actual values. So if I change it to "this" it will issue another error: `error: invalid use of 'this' at top level`. How do I resolve this? Also I don't want to modify the callable after initialization (adapted in example for constness)

Comment: @user17732522 I just recently switched to C++20, I will have a look at concepts now

Comment: @glades to get an expression of a type without having an actual object you can use `std::declval` in an unevaluated operand such as `decltype`: `std::declval<some_struct*>()`

Comment: @user17732522 Ahh that's what declval is for! Thank you fixed it on this bases! :)